# Ajuda com arrays java

Tags: java, array, string

Tenho o array disciplinas e o array atual.

O atual é uma cópia exata do disciplinas. Caso haja duas Strings iguais dentro do array disciplinas eu preciso excluir todas iguais e manter apenas uma.

Ou seja, o atual não deve conter strings repetidas.

Alguém pode ajudar com este código?

```
String coisa = "";
String[] atual = disciplina.clone();;
int conta = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < disciplina.length; j++) {
  if (disciplina[j] != null && nota[j] != 0) {
      if(atual[j].equals(disciplina[j])){
        atual[j] = "";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Os dois são `ArrayList` de `String`?

Comment: nao sao arraylists, nao estou usando o collections, apenas arrays

Comment: Por que você não pode usar Collections?

Comment: É exercicio de faculdade, provavelmente.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"teste1", "teste2", "teste1"};
    String[] b = new String[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(arrayNaoContemString(b, a[i])) {
            b[i] = a[i]; 
        }
    }
    for (String string : b) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static boolean arrayNaoContemString(String[] array, String string){
   for(String s : array){
       if (string.equals(s)){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

[Veja o resultado no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ve1q9c). Ou veja [essa pergunta no SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128723/3892340) para mais soluções.

Comment: Só cuidado com exceção de ponteiro nulo, caso o argumento de `arrayNaoContemString` seja nulo

Comment: Sim, mas é bem restrito o uso do método, então não achei necessário colocar.

Comment: E muito provavelmente nesse exercício nunca haverá uma entrada nula. Mas eu sempre creio ser auspicioso levantar que se está assumindo certa entrada ou quais as limitações da solução. Meio que concorda com a Physics Girl nesse vídeo https://youtu.be/oxbuFwW5f-Q

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `Set` que não permite duplicados.

```
Set<String> disciplinas = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(disciplina));

disciplina = disciplinas.toArray(new String[disciplinas.size()]);
```

---

> [**`Set`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
>
> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma coleção que não contém itens duplicados. Mais formalmente, sets não contém pares de elementos e1 e e2 em caso de e1.equals(e2). Como sugere o nome, essa interface é uma abstração do modelo matemático "conjunto".

---

Uma sugestão de resolução sem usar `Collection`:

```
public String[] removerDuplicados(String[] base) {
  String[] resultado = new String[base.length];
  int contador = 0;
  boolean encontrado;

  for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
    String elemento = base[i];

    encontrado = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < resultado.length; j++) {
      if (resultado[j] == null) {
        break;
      }

      if (resultado[j].equals(elemento)) {
        encontrado = true;
      }
    }

    if (!encontrado) {
      resultado[contador] = elemento;
      contador++;
    }
  }

  return Arrays.copyOfRange(resultado, 0, contador);
}
```

---

Outra forma é ordenar o `array` e depois apenas comparar com o registro anterior para inserir em um outro, sem os duplicados:

```
public String[] removerDuplicados(String[] base) {
  String[] resultado = new String[base.length];
  String anterior = null;
  int indice = 0;

  Arrays.sort(base);

  for (String atual : base) {
    if (atual != null && (anterior == null || !atual.equals(anterior))) {
      resultado[indice] = atual;
      indice++;
    }

    anterior = atual;
  }

  return Arrays.copyOfRange(resultado, 0, indice);
}
```

---

Aplique da os dois métodos acima da seguinte forma:

```
disciplina = removerDuplicados(disciplina);
```

Comment: tenho q fazer só com array, do tipo String

Comment: @cicada3301 essa informação não consta na sua pergunta, porém coloquei mais duas alternativas que talvez atendam ao que você está procurando.

Comment: Obrigado por mostrar a solução `o(n log n)`! Estava me sentindo mal por não ter essa solução

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado só não sei se o uso do `java.utils.Arrays` é permitido pro uso dele, mas aí ele implementa na mão o `sort` né

Comment: Eu ia aproveitar um `merge sort` que eu tenho de outra resposta =) Mas essa solução já atende meus anseios perfeitamente

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas você tava com a mesma dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
if (!atual.contains(disciplina[j])){
    atual.add(disciplina[j])
}
```

Assim caso o array `atual` não contenha o conteúdo de `discplina[j]` ele irá adicionar

Comment: o contains só poder ser usado em arraylist, no caso estou usando somente array de string, sem o collections